# Stack Using Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I'm trying to create a stack using linked lists in c++. But the display function i have written prints only the top of the stack. I can't really understand why this is happening. Any help or clarification is much appreciated. Thanks

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Node
{
protected:

    Node* next;
    int data;

public:

    Node(int d){data=d;}
    friend class Stack;
};

class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(){top->next='\0';length=0;}

void push(int d)
{
    Node *n=new Node(top->data);
    n->next='\0';
    top->next=n;
    top->data=d;
    length++;
}

int pop()
{
    top=top->next;
    length--;
    return top->data;
}

void displaystack()
{
    while(top->next!='\0')
    {
        cout<<top->data<<endl;
    top=top->next;
    }
}

int getlength()
{
    return length;
}

private:
    Node *top;
    int length;

};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    Stack s;
    s.push(9);
    s.push(8);
    s.push(7);
    s.push(6);
    s.push(5);
    s.push(3);
    s.displaystack();
    int len=s.getlength();
    cout<<"length of stack is "<<len<<endl;
    getch();
}
```

It only prints the following:
3
the length of stack is 6

--------xxxxxxx-------xxxxxxxx--------xxxxxxx-----------xxxxxxxxxxxxx--------------

After editing the code looks like this: 
and works too! (thanks to @Kaathe) :P

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Node
{
protected:
Node* next;
int data;

public:

Node(int d){data=d;}
friend class Stack;
};

class Stack
{
public:
Stack(){top->next=NULL;length=0;}
~Stack()
{
     while(top!=NULL)
 {
   Node* toDelete=top;
   top=top->next;
   delete toDelete;
 }

}

void push(int d)
{
Node *n=new Node(d);
n->next=top;
top=n;
length++;
}

int pop()
{
 Node* oldtop=top;
 top=top->next;
 int oldtopdata=oldtop->data;
 delete(oldtop);
 --length;
 return oldtopdata;
}

void displaystack()
{
Node* current=top;
while(current->next!=NULL)
    {
    cout<<current->data<<endl;
    current=current->next;
    }
}

int getlength()
{
return length;
}

private:
Node *top;
int length;

};
```

Comment: I cannot see how you initialize top of stack. "n->next='\0'; top->next=n;" should be "n->next= top->next; top->next=n;"

Comment: I'm trying to copy the data of "top" into n and make "top" point to "n"
like this : 
top(points to n)->n(points to null)

Comment: Thank you! JackyZhu
Got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `push`, you want to create an entirely new `Node`, set its data to the value `d`, and point it at the old top of the stack. You can then set the top of the stack to this new node. You actually don't need to modify the old top node at all.

So push could read:

```
void push(int d)
{
    Node* newTop = new Node(d);
    newTop->next = top;
    top = newTop;
    ++length;
}
```

I just noticed that `pop` also won't behave as expected, as you throw away the top node, and return the data in the node below it. Maybe you could write:

```
int pop() 
{
    Node* oldTop = top;
    top = top->next;
    int oldTopData = oldTop->data;
    delete(oldTop);
    --length;
    return oldTopData;
}
```

It would probably also be a good idea to stop people from popping empty stacks (for example by checking that `length >= 1` at the start of `pop()`.

Finally, `displaystack` will kind of destroy the `Stack` object if called, by losing the pointer to the top node. Maybe this would be better:

```
void displayStack()
{
    Node* currNode = top;
    while(currNode->next != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << currNode->data << std::endl;
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
}
```

It makes more sense to me to end the linked list with a `nullptr` too.

Also, the stack should have a destructor which `delete`s all its `Node`s - I'll let you write that one ;)

Comment: Question:
Is putting a"nullptr" in *next not the same as putting '\0' ?


Thank you so much @Kaathe for your patience! I know the mistakes are so naive!

Comment: '\0' is an end-of-string character - it's of type char. I would guess that it must automatically convert to 0 when you assign it to a pointer type, but writing nullptr makes it clearer what you are trying to do - finish the linked list with a pointer that points to null, rather than a Node.

Comment: `~Stack()
 {
   while(top!=NULL)
  {
    Node* toDelete=top;
    top=top->next;
    delete toDelete;
  }

 }`

Answer (score 0):

When you print (in `displaystack`) you should use a temporary variable instead of destructively updating the top variable.

To avoid a memory leak in `pop()` you should also `delete` the node previously allocated using `new`.

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if your program works if you still have this in your code:

```
Stack(){top->next=NULL;length=0;}
```

Solution is left as exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: could you please elaborate ?
because the program is running!
please give me a condition under which it won't ?

Comment: its working both, when i use `top->next=NULL` AND `top=NULL`.
please help me understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `while(top->next!='\0')` to `while(top!='\0')`
It should work then...