# Linked list implementation of stack in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to use simple Push, Pop and Show function in stack as a linked list implementation.  The Push function is working correctly I think, but I am having trouble with the Show and Pop. Whenever I use the Pop function, I get only one result and the next time it says, "*Stack Empty!!*".  I am doing a logical error I think.  Please help me with that.  I am using Turbo C++ 4.5.  I am posting the code below.  Thanks in advance!

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *link;
};
node *temp, *top;
void PUSH()
{
    temp=new node;
    cout<<"\nEnter data item:";
    cin>>temp->data;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(top==NULL)
    {
        temp->link=top;
        top=temp;
    }
}

void POP()
{
    if(top==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nEmpty";
        return;
    }
    temp=top;
    top=top->link;
    cout<<"\nDeleted value is : "<<temp->data;
    temp->link=NULL;
    delete(temp);
}

void SHOW()
{
    if(top==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nEmpty!!";
        return;
    }
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->data<<endl;
        temp=temp->link;
    }
}

void main()
{   int ch;
    do{
    cout<<"\nEnter your choice";
    cout<<"\n1.Push\n2.Pop\n3.Show\n4.Exit";
    cin>>ch;
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1: PUSH();
        break;
        case 2: POP();
        break;
        case 3: SHOW();
        break;
        case 4: exit(0);
        break;
    }
    }while(ch!=4);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: It does not look like you initialized `top` to be `NULL` in `node *temp, *top;`, but you checked if `top` was `NULL` in `PUSH()`

Comment: Please read up on OOP (you have that with C++).. Also using the standard library - this is already done for you with a template

Comment: Why are you using an ancient compiler?

Comment: Till I pass High school, I'll have to stick with that only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to clear ur concepts about implementing stack through linked list.....

Your PUSH function should look something like this

```
void PUSH()
{
    temp=new node;
    cout<<"\nEnter data item:";
    cin>>temp->data;
    temp->link=NULL;
    if(top==NULL)
        top=temp;      
    else
    {
        temp->link=top;    
        top=temp;
    }
}
```

The POP function is declared void so it must not return any value...and the correct declaration should be

```
void POP()
{

    if(top==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nEmpty";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nDeleted value is : "<<top->data;
        temp=top;
        top=top->link;
        delete(temp);
    }

}
```

And in the SHOW function, the else part should be

```
        temp=top;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<endl;
            temp=temp->link;
        }
```

And I will suggest you should use Codeblocks as it has much cleaner and simpler UI than Turbo C++.

You can clear your concepts through this post [Stack Using Linked List in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430048/stack-using-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I know that, but my school bounds me to use Turbo until I pass high school.

Answer (score 1):

After 2nd Push you don't link your `temp` node to existing 'stack'.

```
if(top==NULL)
{
    temp->link=top;
    top=temp;
}
```

Why do you need this if? I guess you have to update `top` node every time in Push method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `PUSH` function, you only actually do anything with the new `node` if `top` is `NULL`, so all pushes onto a nonempty stack are ignored (except that they leak memory).  Try it like this instead.

```
void PUSH() {
    temp = new node;
    cout << "\nEnter data item:";
    cin >> temp->data;
    temp->link = top;
    top        = temp;
}
```

Comment: It's fine, but still, my Pop and Show functions are not working.  They are showing and deleting the last data only. Please help.